# Google Sheets Script App - Validate cell color then save record to database

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write the code to validate if a cell color is '00ff40' (green), if true then save to the database. If the cell color is not '00ff40' (green) then ignore and don't save to the database.

```
This is my attempt at validating the cell color.
```

```
//Validating Cell Color #00ff40 (green)
  if (shUserForm.getRange("B6")=='00ff40'){
      
      ui.alert("Color is not green.");
      shUserForm.getRange("B6").activate();
      shUserForm.getRange("B6").setBackground("FF0000");
      return false;

  }

  return true;
```

```
The cell values are being populated even though the cell color is not '00ff40' (green).
```

```
if(validateEntry()==true){

  var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row

  //code to update the data in the database

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("B6").getValue());//Happy value in cell
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("D6").getValue());//Focused value in cell
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("F6").getValue());//Ready value in cell
```

I tried modifying the code but it seems not to validate the cell color.

Comment: This does not return values `shUserForm.getRange("B6:F6")`

Comment: Hi Cooper - I just updated to reflect shUserForm.getRange("B6"). Sorry about that.

Comment: `if (shUserForm.getRange("B6")=='00ff40'){`. This won't work; you need to add `getBackground()` to get the background colour of the range. There's an example in the [documentation'(https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground).

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing this answer as a community wiki, since the answer was taken from the comments section, in order to provide a proper response to the question.

To get the Background color of a cell you need to use the `getBackground()` function, this update to your code would evaluate to `true`:

```
  if(shUserForm.getRange("B6").getBackground() == '#00ff40'){
    // Code to run when a cell backgroung color is green/#00ff40
  }
```

Google Documentation - [Range.getBackground()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackground) as provided by [@Tedinoz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1330560/tedinoz).